# Can an object extend functionality through annotations? (SugarORM example)

Tags: java, oop, inheritance, orm, annotations

I notice that in SugarORM, objects are allowed to call `object.save()` even though `save()` is not actually implemented directly in the object and all the object has is annotation `@Table` declared at the top of the class.

How can an object perform a function if all it's doing is using an annotation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Java, an annotation can't *directly* enhance a class; it's simply metadata read by other tools. However, there are some tools that can process annotations and automatically generate additional code. Two examples:

- Spring Roo uses annotations to generate AspectJ inter-type declarations (basically external add-ons for classes) that get compiled into the final class file.
- Lombok uses a compiler extension to support a number of specific annotations that perform transformations on Java (or Groovy) classes, such as adding boilerplate constructors and getters/setters. The approach Lombok uses gets deep into the compiler internals and is fairly brittle.

In Groovy, annotations *can* directly enhance a class, as they can trigger transformations that are applied statically at compile-time. Common transformations include `@ToString` (adds a friendly `toString()` method) and `@EqualsAndHashCode` (generates those methods based on the class's properties).

In this specific case of Sugar ORM, methods such as `save()` are defined on `SugarRecord`, so classes directly extending `SugarRecord` can use them. Alternately, [the test cases involving annotated classes](https://github.com/satyan/sugar/blob/8a4cd588b3827fc804169afb968a6a5bfae99484/library/src/test/java/com/orm/record/IntegerFieldTests.java) use static imports to resolve those methods.

Comment: So if I extend, I can use `.save()`, but if I only annotate, then I use the static class?

Comment: @ArukaJ Basically, yes.

Answer (score 0):

No, annotations can not extend a class's functionality. The annotated class does not automatically get new methods/fields through annotation.

As for Sugar ORM, I don't believe the example code compiles. It's referencing undefined fields and methods. And if you look at the unit tests, they use static methods from `SugarRecord` to save/update purely annotated record class:

```
import static com.orm.SugarRecord.save;
import static com.orm.SugarRecord.findById;

@Test
public void findByIdIntegerTest() throws Exception {
    save(new SimpleAnnotatedModel());
    assertEquals(1L, findById(SimpleAnnotatedModel.class, 1).getId().longValue());
}
```